# Finding the family of curves orthogonal to the brachistochrones

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

I was asked to find and solve the differential equation for the family of curves orthogonal to the family of brachistochrones. This is my work:

The equation of the brachistochorne family is.
$$dy=dx\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-x}}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-x}}$$
Slope of brachistochrones is $\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-x}}$. Slope of synchornes must be orthogonal to this and is $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-x}}}$.
Therefore, the differential equation for the synchornes is $dy=dx\frac{-1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-x}}}$.
Treat this as a separable differential equation to get d$y=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-a}}}dx$
Integrate both sides: $$y=-2a-2a\left(\frac{\arctan{\left(\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-x}}\right)}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x}{a-x}}}{\frac{2x}{a-x}+2}\right)+C$$

Does this look right? The answer seems a bit intense, which is why I would like to verify my work.

Comment: Please clarify - do you mean orthogonality in the geometric sense or the $L^2$ sense?

Comment: @K.defaoite I believe the geometric sense.